# Escaping directory chars in C#

Tags: c#, string, path, escaping

I need to escape chars in a string I have, which content is `C:\\blablabla\blabla\\bla\\SQL.exe` to  `C:\blablabla\blabla\bla\SQL.exe` so I could throw a process based on this SQL.exe file.

I tried with `Mystring.Replace("\\", @"\");` and `Mystring.Replace(@"\\", @"\");` but none worked.

How could I do this?

EDITED: Corrected type in string.

Comment: I see strictly no difference between the input and the expected output. Also are you looking this input string in a debugger?

Comment: Both strings you've mentioned are the same

Comment: Your two values are the same? do you need to turn C:\ into C:\\ or C:\\ into C:\

Comment: The from and to strings you showed are the same.

Comment: How did you get the string with double backslashes anyway? Is it extracted from programming code? And technically, replacing \\ by \ is generally considered as *unescaping*, not escaping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to replace double backslash (`@"\\"`) in a string with single backslash (`@"\"`).  If so try the following

```
Mystring = Mystring.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

Note: Are you sure that the string even contains double backslashes?  Certain environments will print out a single backslash as a double (debugger for example).  Your comment mentioned my approach didn't work.  That's a flag that there's not actually a double backslash in your string (else it would work).

Comment: @noloman, is your code exactly as above, i.e., you are doing the assignment?

Comment: @noloman see my updates. Are you sure there is a double backslash in the string? My sample should work if there is

Comment: well, I get a "System cannot find the file specified" Exception, and in the StackTrace, it's mentioned the string like `D:\\Projects\\..`, so I don't know..

Comment: @noloman the debugger often escapes backslashes giving the appearance that the string contains double `\` characters when really it just has 1.  If the code in my post dosen't change the string then this is almost definitely the case.

Comment: @JaredPar thanks a lot then, because it doesn't change anything; now I just need to figure out the problem, but I still don't know how

Comment: @JaredPar actually yes, you are right (and all you guys who commented below that there could still be only one backslash): using the text visualizer, I see there's only one backslash :)

Answer (score 9):

I very strongly suspect that you are looking this input string in the Visual Studio debugger and fooling yourself that there are actually 2 `\` whereas in reality there aren't. That's the reason why attempting to replace `\\` with `\` doesn't do anything because in the original string there is no occurrence of `\\`. And since you are looking the output once again in the debugger, you are once again fooling yourself that there are 2 `\`.

Visual Studio debugger has this tendency to escape strings. Log it to a file or print to the console and you will see that there is a single `\` in your input string and you don't need to replace anything.

Answer (score 3):

The `@` character specifies a string as a verbatim literal string, but that is when constructing a string. If you use `Mystring.Replace("\\", @"\")` then nothing will be replaced, essentially, as the two strings are the same.

If you want a string without the escape characters, then either define it with:

```
string path = @"C:\Some\Directory\And\File.txt";
```

Or you can replace the `\\` with `/` like so:

```
path = path.Replace('\\', '/');
```

It is worth noting, as mentioned by Darin Dimitrov, that the string containing two `\` characters is likely just the display of the string (i.e. when using the debugger) and not the *actual* value of the string.

Answer (score 1):

i think OP is asking how to escape \\  in File Path, if that in the case, as OP is not mentioning where he's trying to use this. so i'm putting a guess.

Then You use Path.Combine() method to get the FileName path.

[Path.Combine() Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

where are you looking at this output? because it could be the string is what you expect, but viewing the value through the debugger, output window, etc. is escaping the slash

Comment: well, it essentially doesn't start the process, complaining about that it can't find the file

Comment: do you have problem with escaping or finding the file then?

Comment: there are many reasons why it might not be able to find the file. file permissions, bad path, locked file, etc.

Comment: well, I thought it'd be a problem of not replacing because if I use the name of the file to execute, everything's ok, but if I concatenate the actual directory, then it fails

Comment: when you concatenate are you perhaps missing a "\" when concatenating the directory.. I am assuming that you are trying to join directory + some sub directory..

Comment: @DJKRAZE this is what I do: `private string EscapedFilename = (System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\SQLServer2008ExpressWithTools" + "\\SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.EXE");`

Comment: so you are trying to actually hit or locate the file on the Server meaning it's directory or is the instance of SqlServer installed on your local..

Comment: also Look at GetCuttentDirectory() are you trying to get the current Directory of where your current application is running.. ? this looks to be your problem..

Comment: One last question It looks like you did not explain the issue correctly .. are you trying to Spawn another process based on the filename that is being passed to SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.EXE..? if so you want to look at how to implement System.Daignostics.Process and ProcessInfo class.. please clarify my assumptions..

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
myStr = myStr.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

Make sure you assign the result of Replace method to myStr. Otherwise it goes into void ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "|DataDirectory|\MyFile.xyz" where you need it. It works with connection strings it might work with something else (I haven't really tried to apply it to something else).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you want, if you just want do get the file name (escape directory chars) you can try:

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(YourString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Noloman.... when you concatenate are you perhaps missing a "\" when concatenating the directory.. I am assuming that you are trying to join directory + some sub directory.. @noloman keep in mind that in C# "c:\Temp" is written like this "c:\Temp" or @"c:\Temp" one is Literal the other is how to represent a "\" in the legacy way of coding because the "\" is an escape Char and when dealing with directorys we represent all paths and sub paths with "\" 
so perhaps by you replacing the "\" you are truly messing up your own expected process

```
Mystring = Mystring.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

should work for you unless you are truly meaning to do 
Mystring = Mystring.Replace(@"\", "\"); which if you believe that you are expecting a "\" to be used to build the directory.. then of course it will not work.. because you have just in essense replaced the backslash with a return char.. I hope that this makes sense to you..

System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); you are using is also an Issue.. SQL Server is not that application thats running the code.. it's your .NET application so you need to either put the location of the SQL Server into a variable, app.config, web.config ect... please edit your question and paste the code that you are using to do what it is that you want to do inregards to the SQL Server Code.. you would probably want to look at the Are you wanting to do something like Process.Start(....) meaning the file name..?